# Establish connection to remote SSH server with private key for exec, Node.js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ssh, node-modules

Trying to connect to a remote SSH server, Linux Ubuntu virtual machine, and execute commands.

I feel dumb having to ask this, but I've gone through dozens of node modules and cannot find a solution.

I believe it's something wrong on my end, as I'm a novice in coding, but I'm looking to connect to a virtual machine (which runs on Linux, Ubuntu) via SSH in order to execute some commands automatically. As of now, I connect to the server through PuTTY. I use the default port (22), fill in the IP address, and username, and upload my key. After going through a ton of SSH modules, each one gives me nothing: no error, no response, nothing - apart from, sometimes, "All configured authentication methods failed." This makes me assume I'm somehow linking my key incorrectly. I fill out the private key path like so: `key:`  - or whatever the option name is - `require('fs').readFileSync('./keys/key.key')` or just `readFileSync('./keys/key.key')` if fs has already been acquired. I've filled in the path if the option only required the path, and I've attempted to use `Buffer.from()` as well, although I'm not too familiar with it. The key is defaultly in RSA format, but I've also converted it to OpenSSH using `ssh-keygen` to no avail. I've tried using keyboard-interactive, but, the host does not require this, and no keyboard-interactive prompts come up at all. I've tried adding a passphrase to the key, and nothing. I don't know what to do, and I cannot find an answer anywhere online.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find an answer after days of searching. Turns out, there is a prompt regarding host authenticity which must be resolved. I didn't notice this at all considering I had already accepted it on my preferred SSH client and it never prompted me again - the prompt also had its own grandiose UI, so I didn't know it was intrinsic, but I rather assumed it was of the client itself. I wasn't able to fix this using keyboard-interactive, but I was able to modify the options of the `ssh` command in the child process method `exec`. Here's the code:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const command = 'ssh -tt -i ./keys/key.key -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host command';
/* replace user, host, and command with desired options */
exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  process.stdout.write(stdout);
});
```

This bypassed the authenticity prompt as it tricks the system into believing it is already a known host.